# keyboard input stopped being accepted after login

Tags: macos, keyboard

I just disabled my screensaver successfully by entering my password, then after that my machine no longer accepts keyboard input.  The only thing I was able to do is change windows with option-left/right/up/down, but no other keys worked.  The mouse worked.

I have ssh and vnc sessions open.  The VNC session also does not accept keyboard input, so it cannot be a physical problem with the keyboard.  The ssh session does, so the computer is alive and well in some limited sense.

How can I debug this?  Are there any command-line equivalents to `KeyboardViewer.app`?  Any recommendations short of 'reboot the machine' would be very helpful.

(running 10.6.8 on this machine)

Comment: Is this a frequent occurrence? Have you tried to open the force quit menu (CMD + OPT + ESC), if that fails try with a SHIFT too and hold for 30 seconds. Did a reboot help?

Comment: No, first time this has ever happened.  cmd-opt-esc and shift-cmd-opt-escape both do nothing.

Comment: Solved: `killall Dock` fixed it.  Damn.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with any apps or utilities that might intercept USB devices. I once had a forgotten keyboard tool that was used to alter mapping of command and option keys that was not compatible with a system update and caused a similar problem.

USB Overdrive? Keyboard macros? Virtual machine apps? Any similar things could be capturing the USB input from the keyboard and failing to pass to the OS.

Comment: This is a great idea.  I don't have USB Overdrive.  Not sure what keyboard macros could possibly get in the way.  Any ideas of how to search for these?